# Output capturing and make under Cygwin: "Unable to initialize device PRN"

Tags: bash, make, cygwin

A minimal example of the problem under Cygwin:

A directory with a `Makefile`:

```
all:
        @echo "foo"
```

and a `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

x=$(make)
print $x
```

Now `bash test.sh` gives:  `Unable to initialize device PRN`

Comment: There is no `print` command in bash, did you mean `printf` or `echo`? This seems to be the error Windows produces when trying to run the Windows commandline tool `print`: [Unable to initialize device PRN in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721404). Do you still have issues if you use `echo`?

Comment: @terdon ok that was indeed the cause. But the minimal example only worked because I unknowingly introduced the exact same typo someone else did introduce many layers deeper in a Makefile. -.- That's why in the real example I thought it had something to do with $( ... ), which in fact is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Ah yes, those are always annoying to debug! I'll close this as non-reproducible then since the issue was something else. Glad you found a solution!